# Older Kenmore dryer won’t shut off after cycle

Tags: dryer, timer

I have an older kenmore dryer that won’t shut off after drying for a timed amount.  It heats up and the timer motor advances to the end-but will run until you open the door or manually advance the timer knob just a hair.  Ive replaced the cycling thermostat and this is the third timer I've tried.  None will shut off after the timed drying cycle.  If I put it on high heat, timer doesn’t advance and just runs indefinitely

Comment: See if you can find the wiring diagram for that model of dryer online.  I am assuming you are using timers for that model(not ones that look the same), so with three timers, it should not be the timer, but something else.

Comment: Replace the timer

Comment: Cant do much with `old dryer` what is the model

Answer (score 1):

You could keep replacing timers, but maybe it's time to look for another fault like a bad crimp at the spade connector on the end of a wire.

Get out your ohmmeter or continuity tester. For every wire that connects to the timer, connect one probe to the wire's connector and trace that wire to wherever it terminates. It might terminate in another spade connector, or an edge connector or a plug, or it may terminate directly on a circuit board. That's where your other probe goes.

Look for zero or near zero ohms, or a beep if you're testing continuity. Any wire that does not have continuity end to end should be repaired.

Hope you find it!